# Set colunn order of datagrid programmatically

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I was wondering if you can set the column order programmatically in the kendo-grid for angular2?
I see in the documentation that there is a property columnIndex.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns will be displayed in the order that they are set in the configuration. What you can do is pass an array of columns, loop them with `*ngFor`. And then reorder that array, so the changes will be reflected in the UI.